# Refresh ListView with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a ListView with a delete button on each item.I want when the button is pressed the item to be removed from data(An ArrayList of HashMaps) and dismiss from ListView too.

Here is My Code:

BaseAdapter:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

 private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list;

 private Context context;

 public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list,Context  context){

    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if(view == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addresslist_item, null);



        TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listtxtaddress);

        String add = String.valueOf(list.get(position).get("address"));

        address.setText(add);

        Button btndelete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.listbtndelete);

        btndelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("check", "item_positiona:"+position);
                Log.d("check", "lista:"+list.toString());

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                builder.setTitle("Τιτλος επιχειρησησης");

                builder.setMessage("Θέλετε να διαγάρψετε αυτή τη διεύθυνση;");

                builder.setNegativeButton("NAI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                        Log.d("check", "item_positionb:"+position);


                        list.remove(position);

                        notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                });

                builder.setPositiveButton("AKYPO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                AlertDialog abc = builder.create();

                abc.show();



            }
        });


    }

    return view;


}
}
```

My problem is that the item is removed from data but the when ListView is update only the last item is removed and not the item that i select.Any ideas why this happening? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

After the `ArrayList` has changed, you must call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update your `ListView` with the changes.  This can be done inside or outside the adapter.  So, for example:

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    //TIP: Don't make this static, that's just a bad idea
    private ArrayList<Contact> searchArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> initialResults) {
        searchArrayList = initialResults;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void updateResults(ArrayList<Contact> results) {
        searchArrayList = results;
        //Triggers the list update
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: And where exactly do i have to call the updateResults method?

Comment: This is not helpful as OP's problem is not the updating listview but wrong item is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your Adapter object once you've modified the data should refresh the listview.

You can try this-

Create a private class ViewHolder inside your adapter. This class should contain all the views which your list item has.

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView address;
    String add;
    Button btndelete;
}
```

And then inside getView() :

```
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
       if (convertView == null) {     
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.addresslist_item, null);
                viewHolder.address =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listtxtaddress);
                viewHolder.add = String.valueOf(list.get(position).get("address"));
                viewHolder.address.setText(add);

            viewHolder.btndelete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.listbtndelete);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
     else 
   {                


    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

   } 
    viewHolder.btndelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.d("check", "item_positiona:"+position);
                    Log.d("check", "lista:"+list.toString());

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                    builder.setTitle("Τιτλος επιχειρησησης");

                    builder.setMessage("Θέλετε να διαγάρψετε αυτή τη διεύθυνση;");

                    builder.setNegativeButton("NAI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.dismiss();

                            Log.d("check", "item_positionb:"+position);


                            list.remove(position);

                            notifyDataSetChanged();


                        }
                    });




    builder.setPositiveButton("AKYPO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();



                    }
                });

                AlertDialog abc = builder.create();

                abc.show();



            }
        });


    }
    }
    return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work.The same result the last item is removed.It looks like decreasing only the list.size() but keep the same data.

Comment: @user3734693 The issue might be that List is updated but the updated list doen't appear.Since the size of list decreses by one it only hides the last item of the list and  u see the last item being removed.If after deleting item u go back to the previous fragment/activity and then return to the list fragment/activity u should see the correct item being removed.Try replacing all your adapter calls with list.getAdapter() calls.

Comment: I tried everything but the same result! I also add the activity take a look to see if something goes wrong there...thanks!

Comment: I have added new answer to the question..plzz try that..its easy to implement and let me know if you find any issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way also..
Create a Listener interface

```
package xyz.listeners;

public interface DeleteClickListener {

    public void onDeleteClick(int position);

}
```

Than in your actvity/fragment that has listview-

```
private DeleteClickListener mDeleteClickListener;
mDeleteClickListener = new DeleteClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDeleteClick(int position) {

     list.remove(position);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
```

In your adapter class contructor pass that listener.

```
public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list,Context  context,DeleteClickListene mDeleteClickListener){

    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
    deleteClickListener=mDeleteClickListener;

}
```

and then onClick of Delete button

```
builder.setNegativeButton("NAI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                              deleteClickListener.onDeleteClick(position);




                            }
                        });
```

Comment: just made few corrections in the code above..try tht